# Fatal error: Class 'nz_scm_walker' not found in /home/cilclhk/public_html/wp-content/themes/primetrans/includes/header-opt.php on line 52

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having this issue while transferring WordPress website from one domain to another(Both domains are on different hosting server).
May be the following info is required...
PHP Version used: 5.6.33
hosting: Labelhost

Also when I access to wp-admin, It is redirecting me to older domain's admin panel. e.g, My website is live on www.xyz.com/abc(Sorry actually it is in ssubdomain & not on main domain). So I am migrating this website to another domain i.e, www.example.com(yeah this is main domain & not sub-domain)

So, when I try to access www.example.com/wp-admin it redirects me to www.xyz.com/abc/wp-admin

So, what's causing this issue?

Please ask for any additional info if required.

Comment: 1. Class not found , I guess its cause of plugin or theme which is not yet installed on the migrated website. 2. Redirection , I guess its cause by you just copy and dump the mysql database , where there is setting of the homepage url. So it is using old ur. You need to change it.

Comment: hi @cjmling thnx for reply...but I checked every plugins and theme they are installed properly. Is there anything to do with PHP version?

Comment: Don't think its php version problem. Are you sure they are activated as well? You may try to use search that `nz_scm_walker` world in your themes folder to check where is it defined and how it is being used.

Comment: 'walker'         => new nz_scm_walker. This is the line 52. But surprisingly I copy paste header-opt.php file from old domain to the new one, but doen't work for me. As you can visit www.feststore.in/logistics website it is working without error.

Comment: You also need to find where that `nz_scm_walker` class is actually defined. Is is also copied properly ? Could be in another file or folder.

Comment: I think this is useful info...I will check it. Thank you....!

Comment: No sorry, but I zipped the entire files and folders from one domain. So how could be the lost of files is possible.

Comment: I tried deleting that line of error & the page goes blank.

Comment: the problem is with bad migration. As I can guess, you missed some replacing from db ( old urls to new ). first fix that part, and ony after it check php errors